# Inserting from dataframe to table using psycopg2: array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2

I want to insert data from a dataframe into a table using psycopg2, but when I try to insert, it shows a message that the array must start with "{" or dimension information.
Here's my code:

```
for f in df.iterrows():
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO NumCasos VALUES (%s, %s)",(df.iloc[m, 0],df.iloc[m, 1].item()))
```

And here's the error that shows up:

```
InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "UlPkw" 
LINE 1: INSERT INTO NumCasos VALUES ('UlPkw', 303)
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

I'm not sure how to correct this issue, if anyone knows it would be awesome if you could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column of your table must of an array type.  But you trying to insert a string, not an array of strings.

How to fix it depends on what you are trying to do.  You could change the type of that column in the table so it just holds simple strings.  You could change your program so that df.iloc[m, 0] held a python array, which it would automatically convert to a PostgreSQL array upon binding.  You could wrap it into a single-element python array on the fly:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO NumCasos VALUES (%s, %s)",([df.iloc[m, 0]],df.iloc[m, 1].item()))
```

Or could change the text stored in `df.iloc[m, 0]` so that it looks like PostgreSQL's idea of a valid array literal, by (in this case) just adding curly braces as the first and last characters of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed the datatype to varchar and it worked :) 
The curly braces solution also worked, so thanks!!